# Error 500 when deploying with vercel an app of nextjs and mongodb

Tags: next.js, vercel

//This is my index code "/" which I think is the error, which is the fetch with the localhost, what happens is that I do not know how to change that localhost:3000 when deploying to Vercel. Does anyone have a solution?

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/tasks");

  const tasks = await res.json();

  console.log(tasks);

  return {
    props: {
      tasks,
    },
  };
```

Comment: You can use relative url like "/api/tasks". This should resolve correctly to 
 [your_website_host]/api/tasks.

Comment: You shouldn't make calls to your own API routes on `getServerSideProps`, `getStaticProps` or `getStaticPaths`. More about this [on the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#getserversideprops-or-api-routes).